# error: cannot find -lc++ clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm having no luck running the Qt examples with Qt Creator. I've tried three so far, but I have been unable to build and run any of them. 
and also it showing as QML module not found for QtQuickVirtualKeyboard import.

i have attached the error screenshot.

error: cannot find -lc++
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

[image]

Comment: This sounds similar to Qt issue; https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76787 .

Comment: Which KIT are you using for the build, and what Qt creator version do you have? (I assume you installed VirtualKeyboard )

Comment: E linker  : normalize_path - invalid input: "C", the input path should be absolute
W linker  : Warning: unable to normalize "C"
E linker  : normalize_path - invalid input: "C", the input path should be absolute
W linker  : Warning: unable to normalize "C"

"org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore" died.

The application is getting build now but it's getting crashed by giving above error messages.


Regarding VirtualKeyBoard, i don't have much knowledge how to install. It will be helpful if you guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

The error: cannot find -lc++ using ndk r20 can be solved like this:
https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/264903/9/mkspecs/android-clang/qmake.conf#34][1]

For example to compile for android armv7 ndk r20, locate the file:
**C:\Qt\5.13.0\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang\qmake.conf**
and add the missing **-nostdlib++**
for android x86 (i use this for emulator), locate the file:
**C:\Qt\5.13.0\android_x86\mkspecs\android-clang\qmake.conf**